# Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo este código

***takings-app.js:***

```
angular
    .module("TakingsApp",["ngRoute"])
    .config(function($routeProvider){ 
        $routeProvider
            .when("/",{
               controller: "ListCtrl",
               templateUrl:"listTaking.html"   //cargar esta vista(templateUrl) con este controlador
            })
            .when("/edit/:film",{
                controller:"EditCtrl",
                templateUrl:"editTaking.html"
            });
    });

console.log("TakingsApp initialized.");
```

***editTaking-contrl.js:***

```
/* global angular */

    angular
        .module("TakingsApp")
        .controller("EditCtrl",
                        ["$scope",
                        "$http", 
                        "$routeParams",
                        "$location",
        function ($scope,$http,$routeParams,$location){
            console.log("Edit Controller initialized.");
```

***listTaking-ctrl.js:***

```
var app = angular.module("TakingsApp");

  app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
      console.log("ListCtrl initicialized!");
```

***Salida consola Google:***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He puesto las inicializaciones solo de los archivos .js , ya que el error supuestamente es de la inicialización del módulo o de algún controlador pero no sé la verdad. ¿En qué fallo?

***index.html:***

```
<html ng-app="TakingsApp">

<head>
    <title>Ingresos cine español</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="editTaking-ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="listTaking-ctrl.js"></script>

</head>

</head>

<body ng-view>

    </body>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes declarados esos ficheros en el fichero HTML? El error dice que no encuentra el módulo, quizá lo estás intentando importar antes de declararlo

Comment: Tengo varios html pero donde tengo importado angular, angular-route y demás , lo que tengo es el body solo con una etiqueta ngView , ya que el resto de código html lo tengo divido en edithtml y listhtml

Comment: Pero ¿en qué orden? ¿estás seguro de que estás importando takings-app **antes** que editTaking-contrl ?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con el index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No has importado el fichero `takins-app.js`, por lo que [el módulo no está declarado](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod). Asegúrate de añadirlo antes de los otros dos ficheros pero después de los ficheros de AngularJS:

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="takings-app.js"></script> <!-- Falta éste -->
<script src="editTaking-ctrl.js"></script>
<script src="listTaking-ctrl.js"></script>
```